# MySQL rows with multiple ids as conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table meant for assignments. These assignments have multiple requirements (things users need to have in order to be allowed to take the assignment). I have these requirements as id's from a requirements table.

I want users to get the assignments they meet the requirements for. So I have a set of ids that a user has in php, and I need to query the assignments who only ask for the ids that that user has, or less.

I thought to create a json array with all the requirements and put it in a column in the assignments table. Then also create a json array with the requirements the user has, and then use it in a LIKE query.

But I found out that wouldn't work.

For example, I have ["6","9","11"] as requirements and 6 7 9 11 12 what the user has.

The requirements themself would fit into the ones that the user has (using %"6"% etc), not the other way around.

So my question is, how can I search in my assignments table, somehow supplying the ids that the user has, and only get the rows that meet the ids that the user has, or less.

I could also make a table for the requirements, instead of a column, with for each requirement a row, but then I don't know how to search that in one query as well.

Comment: Breaking requirements out into a separate table is absolutely the right way to go about this.  Any time you are storing multiple values in one column, huge red flags should be going up.

Comment: Yes I thought so. But is it possible to supply the ids? Or would I really need to select all assignments first, and then check with php if the requirements meet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have a way I'm using now..

I have a subquery in the WHERE; which queries the `assignment_requirements` and left joins the `user_met_requirements`, and I've put both COUNT(`assignment_id`) and COUNT(`user_id`) in a HAVING, so in case a `user_id` is NULL, it means it won't have the requirement, and it won't count up to the `assignment_id`, so it will ignore that row.

This does mean that I have a small overhead, I think, because each assignment is being subqueried.

I'll leave the question open for a little while in case someone has a better idea, else I'll stick with this.

Answer (score 1):

You should create some associative tables. You can read more about associative tables [on this website](http://www.phpbbdoctor.com/blog/2007/02/04/database-design-1-using-associative-tables/).

In your case, you'll end up with the following tables:

- `assignments` (`assignment_id`)
- `requirements` (`requirement_id`)
- `assignment_requirements` (`assignment_id`, `requirement_id`)
- `users` (`user_id`)
- `user_met_requirements` (`user_id`, `requirement_id`)

`assignment_requirements` and `user_met_requirements` are associative tables
Afterwards you can use a join to find all assignments that satisfy the requirements:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM `assignments` a
JOIN `assignment_requirements` ar
    ON (a.`assignment_id` = ar.`assignment_id`)
JOIN `user_met_requirements` umr
    ON (umr.`requirement_id` = ar.`requirement_id`)
WHERE umr.user_id = "$YOUR_USER_ID"
GROUP BY a.id
```

This will give you a list of available assignments.
This is pretty untested so the right answer might be slightly different, but this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it working. Is it correct that I have to do a group by on a.id? Else I'm getting one assignment as many times as that there are requirements.

Comment: Now I'm not sure, it seems that you only have to meet one row in user_met_requirements, the other rows in assignment_requirements are just ignored. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're right, I'm selecting only the completed requirements. I'd take another look later on, don't really have the time now.

Comment: I haven't been able to come up with a solution for it myself so it's much appreciated.